# Quotation marks in Beamer

Tags: beamer, punctuation

I have something like this

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=Crimson]{structure} 
\usetheme[height=7mm]{Rochester} 
...
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
In fact
\begin{align*}
  ``Formula''
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(the `Formula` needs to be in math mode) and I get

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try ending with `"` (single character) instead of two `'`.

Comment: Better, load the `amsmath` package and use `\text{``Formula''}`

Comment: @Fran: That actually looks like it works, but then I loose the coloring of the code in Emacs.

Comment: @AlanMunn: That seemed to do it! So I did `\text{``} Formula \text{''}`.

Comment: @Thomas That's not quite the idea.  See my answer. (Unless you intend that *Formula* is actually a math expression (but then why would you want quotation marks around it...))

Comment: @AlanMunn: I need quotations around it because it isn't quite correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are inside math mode, the single quote character has a different meaning. Since quotation marks proper are part of the text, a better way to do this is to use the `amsmath` `\text` command.  Since you want to put an actual math expression inside the quotation marks you need to put just the quotes themselves in the `\text{}` macro.  If this is something you might do often, then turning it into a macro might be a good idea too.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=Crimson]{structure} 
\usetheme[height=7mm]{Rochester} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
  \text{``}a^2 + b^2 = c^2\text{''}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```